# Documentation about user32.dll and advapi.dll

Tags: dll, c#, decompile

I try to decompile an executable which is something like key-logger, and it references these 2 dlls in which I cannot drill down:

[image]

Any idea/help please of where to find more information/documentation about these? I mean their api contracts.

**UPDATE:**

It is difficult to identify which methods of it are called, because in the decompiled code there is code like that:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hInstance, int threadId);
public void Start()
{
    if (hKeyboardHook == 0)
    {
        this.KeyboardHookProcedure = new HookProc(this.KeyboardHookProc);
        hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(13, this.KeyboardHookProcedure, Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0]), 0);
        if (hKeyboardHook == 0)
        {
            this.Stop();
            throw new Exception("SetWindowsHookEx ist failed.");
        }
    }
}
```

Take a look at the following line:
`Marshal.GetHINSTANCE(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetModules()[0])`

It does not have the method name explicitly...

That is why I am trying to guess

Comment: File path: `"C:\Windows\System32\advapi32.dll"`. Which information do you want to know?

Comment: Thank you @Biswapriyo, actually I mean the api documentation (the methods of it, signatures etc). What i am trying to do is to verify that this "utility" does not do any malicious work (like sending my data somewhere out there)

Comment: OMG! So, your question is toooo broad. There is a whole website docs.microsoft.com for your answer.

Comment: sorry about that, I made it more specific, I need their microsoft documentation

Comment: I updated the question. Is it a little bit more clear now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88945/discussion-between-cnom-and-biswapriyo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both advapi32.dll and user32.dll are completely standard DLLs that come with Windows. And both export a great many functions.

In general Microsoft does not document their APIs by grouping them by DLL; rather, in the documentation for each API, the DLL that exports it will be mentioned, along with the .lib file and the .h file.

For example, see [this reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) for the MessageBox function (from User32), or [this one](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getusernamea) for GetUserNameA from AdvApi32.

In general, User32 contains APIs that help an app create and implement the standard Windows GUI (i.e. a character-mode app, or service process, probably won't use many of these), and AdvApi32 contains "higher level" base API functions (the "lower level" being in kernel32.dll).

These DLLs do not export C# methods. They export functions callable from C/C++.

However, many C# methods will correspond, more or less directly, to these Windows APIs. In most such cases the C# method will call the corresponding C/C++ API to implement its function (after appropriate argument massaging, etc.).

If you want the complete list of what a DLL exports, I suggest you use one of several "dependency walker" tools that are available. Microsoft apparently stopped development of theirs around 2006; [here](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies) is a more recent, open source alternative. If you just want to look things up, look [here](http://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/advapi32/api/) (but Geoff does not appear to have updated these lists since Windows 8).